# Visual Basic, Adding Values To Empty Char Array Elements

Tags: arrays, vb.net, char

I'm having trouble filling up empty array elements in a char array.

I have an **inputArray** that will store all the characters that I type for **myInput** into an array. I then created a **charArray** that will take the characters from **inputArray** and then if it it comes across nothing in the array I want to add -1 to signal empty locations in my **charArray**. I haven't been able to do that. I type "Hello", it will output back to me

```
H
E
L
L
O
Space
Space
Space
Space
And So On, until I reach the end of that array.
*"Space" is for visual aid of output
```

I'm lost. I want to be able to filter out the "-1" and than count for the number of underscores I need to make up the word, like "Hello" would be _ _ _ _ _ (leaving out elements with "-1" or nothing inside of it.)

```
 Module GuessingGame
        Sub Main()
            Dim myInput As String.
            Dim inputArray(11) As Char
            Dim charArray(11) As Char
            Dim myLetter As String
            Dim attempts As Integer = 0
            Dim incorrectAttempts As Integer = 0
            Dim remainingAttempts As Integer = 0

            myInput = InputBox$("Please enter a word or phrase: ")
            inputArray = myInput.ToCharArray()

            While inputArray.Length > 12 
                System.Console.WriteLine("Error: The word or phrase needs to be 12 characters or less")
                myInput = InputBox$("Please enter a word or phrase: ")
                inputArray = myInput.ToCharArray()
            End While

            For i = 0 to inputArray.length - 1
                If IsNothing(inputArray(i)) Then
                    charArray(i) = "-1"
                Else
                    charArray(i) = inputArray(i)
                End If
            Next

            Console.Clear()

            For Each element In charArray
                System.Console.WriteLine(element)
            Next element

            For i = 0 to inputArray.length - 1
                remainingAttempts = remainingAttempts + 1
            Next

            remainingAttempts = remainingAttempts - 1

            System.Console.WriteLine("Guessing Game Display")
            System.Console.WriteLine("---------------------")
            System.Console.WriteLine("Number of Remaining Attempts: " & remainingAttempts)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Number of Incorrect Attempts: " & incorrectAttempts)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Number of Attempts: " & attempts)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Guess a Character? ")
            myLetter = InputBox$("Please enter a character: ")
        End Sub
    End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% but I am pretty sure the IsNothing is checking to see if there is a value at all.. Since you are automatically assigning the array to a size of 11 anything after the H E L L O is going to be set, but either "" or " " just an empty space. So try doing this

```
If inputArray(i) == "" Then
                charArray(i) = "-1"
            Else
                charArray(i) = inputArray(i)
            End If
```

Comment: I tried the fix, but I kept getting an error of Expression Expected. Even if I change it to single "=" it still reading them as blank or space.

Comment: Oh yeah, VB is a single "=" did you try doing = " " and = "" or using the or statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code work fine it must print -1 when there is space in integerArray. But on the code below u must modify it:

```
While inputArray.Length > 12 
   System.Console.WriteLine("Error: The word or phrase needs to be 12 characters or less")
   myInput = InputBox$("Please enter a word or phrase: ")
   '**/*it is better to remove these two code  and replace it by goto above*/**
   inputArray = myInput.ToCharArray()
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by first creating the char array, which would have the input of the word to guess. Then make string arrays, one that had the values from the char array and one that I would use for the guess array to compare off the first string array.

This was the work around to this problem.